# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str simplicity implicitly

Tags: python, string, int, typeerror

so I'm making a script that tries to find the best way to guess a number without guessing over. When I run it I ge this:

line 25, in 
    rt[0]=rt[0]+1
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

And here is my code:

```
import random
guess=10
res=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
n1=[0,0,0]
n2=[0,0,0]
n3=[0,0,0]
n4=[0,0,0]
n5=[0,0,0]
n6=[0,0,0]
n7=[0,0,0]
n8=[0,0,0]
n9=[0,0,0]
gn=0
num=input('num: ')
while guess!=num:
    guess=res[gn]
    print('guess: ' + str(guess))
    guess=str(guess)
    rt=str('n'+(guess))
    guess=int(guess)
    num=int(num)
    if guess>num:
        rt[1]=rt[1]+1
    if guess<num:
        rt[0]=rt[0]+1    
    rt[2]=rt[0]-rt[1]
```

Comment: `rt` is a string (`rt=str('n'+(guess))`) and you are trying to add `1` to it.

Comment: what should be `rt` in the end?

Comment: Rt should be n1, n2, n3, ect.

Comment: Selcuk that's it thanks :)